# How do I draw polygons from aerial imagery?

Tags: arcmap, polygon, polygonize, water

I will be working on a project to automatically identify ponds from satellite imagery. I have uploaded the basemap into ArcMap 10.7, but I can't create a feature layer to start editing. How do I add a blank base layer? I will be tracing the ponds from the basemap (as this is the most detailed imagery I can find). Any other suggestions would be helpful. Could I use another layer instead of the basemap? This is for imagery in Zambia, so any US specific function will not work.

Comment: You can use the tool Create Feature Class https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002p000000 then add fields https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s0000000v000000 make sure your coordinate reference system is either the same as or based on the same datum as your imagery, there's a page on it https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002200000003000000 that mentions some options. For ArcGIS a file geodatabase feature class has the most functionality but is not interchangeable easily, shapefiles have limits but are general.

Comment: Isn't Zambia in Africa? It's not part of the U.S. so you're correct to be careful applying U.S. processes to the data though water is water no matter where it is so some synergy applies. Do you have at least one infra red band? Water has some interesting characteristics in the infra red spectrum, bright on one band dark on another you may be able to use supervised classification https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/interactive-supervised-classification-tool.htm if you have access to a Spatial Analyst extension.